# Orion Context Broker specified IP

Tags: fiware-orion

Is there a method for specific IP address while setting up Orion Context Broker using any of those methods mentioned [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/fiware/orion/)? Now I'm running it as a docker container simultaneously with mongodb. I tried modifying docker-compose file, however couldn't find any network settings for orion.

I recently came across many difficulties with Freeboard and OCB connection and it may be because of OCB running on default loopback interface. It was the same deal when fiware's accumulator server started on that interface and after change to other available the connection was established.

Comment: Just to clarify your question... do you mean how to make Orion to listen on an specific IP interface of the system where it runs?

Comment: As far as I understand orion running as a docker container can be accessed via container's ip gate and additionaly in my situation localhost, because it's the default option for orion to listen on. I don't want the localhost part, I would like to specify the orion's ip myself (i.e. ip from interface other than default loopback). Now I can for sure communicate with OCB via localhost:port as well as ipOfDockerContainerForListening:port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `-localIp` CLI option in order to specify on which IP interface the broker listens to. By default it listens to all the interfaces.